# Как писать НЕ со словом на –мый?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> И никто не узнает об этой маленькой лжи, почти (не)отличимой от правды.

Раньше был печатный словарь на слитное и раздельное написание НЕ с формами на –мый. А теперь что делать? Эти слова далеко не всегда подчиняются правилам причастий. Как же мне скобки-то раскрыть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И никто не узнает об этой маленькой лжи, **почти неотличимой от правды.**

Неотличимый — прилагательное, причастием быть не может (образовано от глагола сов. вида).

Как прилагательное пишется с НЕ раздельно при наличии отрицательных усилительных слов, но наречие ПОЧТИ к усилительным словам не относится.

Пример

Но есть и другой сон, подобный глубокому обмороку, **почти неотличимый от** смерти. [Еремей Парнов. Третий глаз Шивы (1985)]

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае **неотличимый** следует считать прилагательным, т. к. от глаголов совершенного вида(к которым относится и глагол **отличить**) причастия настоящего времени не образуются. Следовательно, надо исходить из правил  правописания имен прилагательных.

Раздельно с не пишутся отглагольные прилагательные на -мый в двух случаях:

1) если от них зависят отрицательные **местоимения или наречия** с частицей **ни** *(ср.: почти неизлечимая болезнь – не излечимая никакими средствами болезнь);*

2) если при них есть частицы **далеко не, отнюдь не и др.** (*ср. у него независимый характер – это отнюдь не зависимый показатель).*

Если слова **на-мый** образовоны от **переходных глаголов несовершенного вида,** то, в зависимости от контекста, они могут быть как **причастиями,** так и **прилагательными.** **Причастиями** такие слова являются при наличии пояснительного слова в творительном падеже (творительного действующего лица или творительного орудия). При других формах пояснительных слов или без пояснительных слов они переходят **в прилагательные и, следовательно, подчиняются общим для прилагательных правилам написания частицы не (теряют значение страдательности, значение времени и приобретают качественное значение);**

> ср.: невидимые слезы, невидимые миру слезы, никому не видимые слезы (прилагательное), не видимые мною слезы (причастие).

Answer (score 2):

Надо определить вид глагола, от которого образовано данное отглагольное образование на -мый.

I) если вид совершенный, то это отглагольное прилагательное и, следовательно, оно пишется по общему правилу правописания прилагательных.

II) если вид несовершенный, то определяем переходность глагола:

```
       1) если непереходный глагол, то это прилагательное и, следовательно, оно пишется по общему правилу правописания прилагательных.

       2) если переходный глагол, то
```

а) если есть зависимое слово в творительном падеже, то это причастие и с *не* пишется раздельно.

б) если нет зависимого слова в творительном падеже, то это прилагательное и оно пишется по общему правилу правописания прилагательных.

Например : (не)заменимый на данной работе сотрудник; никем (не)заменимый сотрудник; отнюдь не заменимый сотрудник.

заменить: вид - совершенный, значит (не)заменимый - прилагательное.

незаменимый на данной работе сотрудник пишем слитно, так как по общему правилу написания прилагательных:

наличие пояснительных слов, как правило, не влияет на слитное написание не с прилагательными.

никем не заменимый сотрудник, отнюдь не заменимый сотрудник пишем раздельно, так как по общему правилу написания прилагательных:

раздельное написание не с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается при наличии в качестве пояснительных слов отрицательных местоимений и наречий (начинающихся с ни) или сочетаний далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не.

Другой пример: (не)любимый ребенок, (не)любимый матерью ребенок, нисколько (не)любимый ребенок, вовсе (не)любимый ребенок

Любить - несовершенный вид, значит, определяем переходность:

так как переходный, то в зависимости от контекста (не)любимый может быть причастием или прилагательным:

не любимый матерью ребенок - есть зависимое слово в творительном падеже, следовательно, это причастие, а потому пишем раздельно.

нелюбимый ребенок, нисколько не любимый ребенок, вовсе не любимый ребенок - нет зависимого слова в творительном падеже, значит это прилагательное и написание подчиняется общим правилам написания прилагательных.

Вывод: надо определить вид и переходность глагола.

Если вид совершенный, то прилагательное.
Если вид несовершенный, смотрим на переходность.
Если непереходный, то прилагательное.
Если переходный, то смотрим, есть ли творительный падеж.
Если есть творительный падеж, то причастие. Пишем раздельно.
Если нет творительного падежа, то прилагательное.
А когда прилагательное, пишем по правилам написания *не* с прилагательными.

Comment: Я в восхищении! (Без шуток.) Это же сколько надо знать, чтобы писать грамотно! С вашей помощью буду повышать свой культурный уровень. )))

Comment: Грамотно ли после точки начинать со строчной? А примеры никак от текста не отделять? Ведь выделено же НЕ в последней строке, значит навык есть!

Answer (score 0):

Как быть со словом "непередаваемые" с зависимым словом СЛОВАМИ? Передавать глагол несовершенного вида, переходный. Значит, НЕ надо писать раздельно? Но везде пишут, что это прилагательное. Значит, оно образовано от глагола ПЕРЕДАТЬ? Или без НЕ не употребляется?